# how to filter rows using Query typed DataSets to show specific rows based on column value (User input) and search box(user input)?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have a database table with the next columns.

[productId] [ArticleNo][Manufacturer][ProductName][ProductDetails][RealStoc][MinimumStoc][MeasurementUnit][Location]

I fill datagridview using Datasources.

I have Two textBoxes ( textBox1 ; textBoxLocationSearch;)

This is my code:

```
      private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string locationValue = textBoxLocationSearch.Text.ToString();
        string searchValue = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        int rowIndex = -1;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue) && row.Cells[8].Value.ToString().Equals(locationValue))
                {
                    rowIndex = row.Index;
                    break;
                }

               
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display in datagridview only the rows that contains specific words inserted by user into textbox1.Text and with the specific cell value and cell index inserted into textBoxLocationSearch.Text.

I mean, i want to get all the rows that contains: apple in the A3 location. It's a location search filter...

I managed to get all rows by user input, and all rows by location input. but never together..

[image: What i want]

Comment: It appears you don't want to sort, but filter the Rows. It's usually done using the data source. If you use a BindingSource, you have the `Filter` property, which supports `LIKE`. Similar if you use a DataTable. If you use another mediator, it must implement a filter logic.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `textBox1.Text.ToString()`: the Text property already returns a string, casting to string is useless.

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks for the info. Could you explain it to me how to `Filter` the Rows using binding Source and  `LIKE`

Comment: You need to specify what the source of the data is. -- [BindingSource.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter) Property. `LIKE` follows the standard rules (including wildcards).

Comment: @Jimi , like  'BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;' ?

Comment: How do you set DataSource of your DataGridView in the first place? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: the data is coming from sql server on Azure website.  and i use Data Source and form load event to populate the dgv.  ` DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string s = dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText;
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'tASDataSet.products' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.productsTableAdapter.Fill(this.tASDataSet.products);`

Comment: So, you have a typed DataSet. See [Query typed DataSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/querying-typed-datasets) -- Add this information to the Question (since this is the important part) and remove the comment. -- You can still use a BindingSource, not just LINQ.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, i will research about Query typed DataSets and try to fix it. i have no clue how to do it.